# Normal Distribution Mayor Question

Tags: probability, statistics

I'm having trouble doing this question from my textbook. If you could help out that would be great!

A Candidate who is running for mayor in a large city, claims that is is favoured by $53\%$ of all eligible voters of that city. Assume that his claim is true. Find the probabilty that in a random sample of $400$ registered voters taken from this city, less than $49\%$ will favor the candidate.

Answer (score 1):

Let $X$ be the number of voters which vote for the Candidate. By assumption $X$ is binomially distributed with $n=400$ and $p=0.53$. The expectation of $X$ is $E[X]=np=212$. The variance of $X$ is $Var[X]=np(1-p)=99.64$. By the Central Limit Theorem $X$ can be approximated by a normal random variable $Y$ with mean $\mu=212$ and $\sigma=\sqrt{99.64}$. Therefore $Z:= (Y-\mu)/\sigma$ is a normalised gaussian random variable, meaning that its distribution function is given by $\Phi$. Hence, $$P[X < 0.49\times 400]=P[X < 196] \approx P[Y < 196]=P[(Y-212)/\sqrt{99.64} < (196-212)/\sqrt{99.64}]=P[Z < (196-212)/\sqrt{99.64}] \approx P[Z < -1.6029]=\Phi(-1.6029) \approx 0.05448$$ Thus, the probability that less than 49% will favor the candidateis approximately 5.448%.